# HTML File including another HTML file

Tags: html, css

I created a web page wherein I want to display there another HTML file. I used jQuery to do this but wasn't able to display the content of the file I have included. Why do you think this happened. Thanks a lot.

Here's my code for my mainpage.

**sample.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Sample Only </title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.js"></script>
    <script> 
        $(function(){
            $('#footerLang').load("sampleFooter.html");
        });
    </script> 


</head>

    <body>

        <div id="footerLang">
            <h1></h1>
        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

**sampleFooter.html**

```
<p> THIS IS A FOOTER </p>
```

Comment: check on Firefox browser

Comment: @LaljiTadhani you're right.

Comment: Ajax nga gamitin mo. Loooool. Kahapon pa to e. Di mo parin nakuha. Hahahaha

Comment: @HermLuna Men browser incompatibility lang ang issue.

Answer (score 2):

It is highly possibly because you are placing the following block in `head` without `$(document).on("ready", function() { ...; });`

```
$(function(){
    $('#footerLang').load("sampleFooter.html");
});
```

In this case `jQuery` will unable to find the `#footerLang` element since the `DOM` is not ready, you could revise the script as follow

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on("ready", function () {
        $('#footerLang').load("sampleFooter.html");
    });
});
```

or move the script tag just before the `</body>`

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Sample Only </title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.js"></script>


</head>

    <body>

        <div id="footerLang">
            <h1></h1>
        </div>

    <script> 
        $(function(){
            $('#footerLang').load("sampleFooter.html");
        });
    </script> 
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that this was just a browser compatibility issue. I launch it in Firefox and it worked.