# Making "personalized variables" in html

Tags: html

Okay, my english is not the greatest so I apologize in advance. Question is really stupid and I dont know how that is called but I will try to explain it here better. So  I am making a template for one restourant and menus are changing every week. So is it possible to write paragraphs somewhere else ( in separated place (external or internal)) and then "call them" somewhere in .html.

Example. making methods in C# and then calling them anywhere when we want to

Comment: I think you want to learn php

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the simplest method will be to use php. 
Then in place with menu you can only use something like this:

```
<?php inlcude('menus/file.php');
```

And on server create a folder menus where you wil put php files with html.

All files can be simple html. There is no need to learn php just in place you want to call a file use code i placed earlier.

Answer (score 0):

HTML doesn't have a *good* way to achieve this (although [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) exists).

This sort of thing is generally handled by software that generates the HTML, either when the page is requested (via something like the very basic SSI support in some webservers to full on server side programming (which you could use C# for)) or at publication time (via a build tool such as Gulp).

Comment: Can it be achieved with php as the Adam said?

*edit* nevermind, I got the answer, thank you!

Comment: PHP is a programming language that can be used for server side programming.

Answer (score -1):

You could use `jQuery` to achieve it (if it is a simple website and simple menu), read more the related function on http://api.jquery.com/load/

You may also read a simple here: [HTML File including another HTML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39264345/html-file-including-another-html-file/39264421#39264421)

I may also include a very basic example for you

main.html

```
<body>
    <header>Some header</header>
    <content>
        <main class="the-menu"></main>
    </content>
    <script>
        $(".the-menu").load("menu.html");
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend an approach based on client side programming, it [isn't entirely reliable](http://kryogenix.org/code/browser/everyonehasjs.html) and is poor food for search engines.

Comment: Agree but it is the simplest way for a person who knows nothing about server side programming. Sometime they just don't need big things to scare them off.